# Loading of DOM and CSS?

Tags: dom

Is Dom loaded before CSS in our webpage ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since the browser uses the DOM to locate elements to be styled, it needs to load the DOM first to do that. This is NOT true of javascript, though (as an aside).